# Wait for serial port input in Go

Tags: io, go, serial-port, system-calls, termios

I have a digital caliper that can send measured value over the serial port.
This data is formatted like `+123.45\r` and can be sent at any time by the device.

So my program needs to "listen" for the first data input (that always ends with a carriage return) and close the reading directly after this one, before continuing his own work.

Dedicated terminals like [CoolTerm](http://freeware.the-meiers.org) and [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html) handle these unpredictable inputs perfectly… But I don't see how to do that in Go (even with cgo).

#### My system

- OS X 10.9.5
- Go 1.4.2 Darwin/AMD64

#### The device

- 4800 baud
- 7 data bits
- Even parity
- 2 stop bits
- DTR

#### My actual code

…that doesn't work…

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("/dev/tty.PL2303-00003014", syscall.O_RDWR+syscall.O_NOCTTY+syscall.O_NDELAY+syscall.O_NONBLOCK, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    // Init terminal for 4800 7E2.
    t := &syscall.Termios{
        // Enable parity checking, strip to 7 bits, CR to NL, outgoing software flow control.
        Iflag: syscall.INPCK + syscall.ISTRIP + syscall.ICRNL + syscall.IXON,
        // Set 4800 bauds, 7 data bits, even parity, 2 stop bits, DTR.
        Cflag:  syscall.B4800 + syscall.CS7 + syscall.PARENB + syscall.CSTOPB + syscall.TIOCM_DTR + syscall.CREAD + syscall.CLOCAL + syscall.CSIZE,
        Cc:     [20]uint8{syscall.VMIN: 1},
        Ispeed: syscall.B4800,
        Ospeed: syscall.B4800,
    }

    _, _, errno := syscall.Syscall(syscall.SYS_FCNTL, uintptr(f.Fd()), uintptr(syscall.F_SETFL), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(t)))
    if errno != 0 {
        panic("syscall error: " + errno.Error())
    }

    // Read until the first new line byte (\r is converted to \n with the ICRNL flag).
    fr := bufio.NewReader(f)
    line, err := fr.ReadBytes('\n')
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(line))
}
```

Comment: You mentioned the values are sent as `xxxx\r`, but you're waiting for `\n`, is that a typo in the post or the code?

Comment: I explain that in the last comment at the end of my code: `\r` is converted to `\n` because of the ICRNL iflag.

Comment: After testing some packages, I just found that [mikepb/go-serial](https://github.com/mikepb/go-serial) does it perfectly and out of the box.
Now I have a good foundation so I will try to do that in pure Go (without cgo) if possible.

Comment: Please post an answer after you figure it out for future reference :)